# Command Button to copy text from textbox to clipboard doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a textbox (Textbox1) and Command Button (cmdButton). I got a vba code from youtube, it seems to work in the video, but when I try it, the text in the textbox will not be copied into the clipboard. How can I fix that?

I renamed the CommandButton1 to cmdButton

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()
    Dim strClipBoard As String
    Set objData = New DataObject

    strClipBoard = Textbox1.Text
    objData.SetText strClipBoard
    objData.PutInClipBoard

    objData.GetFromClipboard
    strClipBoard = ""
   strClipBoard = ObjData.GetText
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code. It seems to be working on my end. Do you have any other details?

Comment: Do I need to activate something in Tools - References? I tried it again, it still doesn't work for me. I have MSO 2016

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/send-information-to-the-clipboard)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Long, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

Public Sub SetClipboard(sUniText As String)
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
    Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
    OpenClipboard 0&
    EmptyClipboard
    iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
    iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
    iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
    lstrcpy iLock, StrPtr(sUniText)
    GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
    CloseClipboard
End Sub

Public Function GetClipboard() As String
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
    Dim sUniText As String
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = 13&
    OpenClipboard 0&
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) Then
        iStrPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
        If iStrPtr Then
            iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
            iLen = GlobalSize(iStrPtr)
            sUniText = String$(iLen \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
            lstrcpy StrPtr(sUniText), iLock
            GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
        End If
        GetClipboard = sUniText
    End If
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

I believe I read somwhere that DataObject is not working because of an upgrade for Win 10 or the cause is  a 64bit office, not sure. I will try to find the source and will post it here.

PS If you use 64bit Office you need to change the API declarations to `longptr`.

**Update**: Not the [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard) I was looking for but at least it seems that *the not working DataObject* is a kind of bug

Comment: I definitely have problems with `DataObject` on Win10/32-bit Office: can't use it to set the clipboard content.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Then you can use the code I posted resp. from the link I provided. As said I read somewhere that there are problems with DataObject and why  but I haven't found the source again.

Comment: I’m already using that code, thanks - just noting the same data object issue on Win10